# Publicar App en Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Quisiera publicar una aplicación en Play store como empresa, pero a la hora de crear una cuenta se debe hacer como una cuenta personal ya que pide nombre, apellido, fecha de nacimiento, etc... Mi duda es si como empresa debería hacerlo de forma diferente o ¿cuál sería la recomendación? ¿Legalmente existe algún problema si creo una cuenta y en campos de nombre y apellido pongo el nombre de la empresa? No quisiera que saliera mi nombre sino el de la empresa a la hora que visitan una App nuestra.

Comment: Debes de llenar esos datos personales como si se tratara del representante legal, es decir, israel x x  con domicilio en x y z, etc, es el contacto de ISRAELAPPS COMPANY. Lo que se mostraria al publico que baje la app es **Developer name**. Mas info en https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No quisiera que saliera mi nombre sino el de la empresa a la hora que
>   visitan una App nuestra.

Lo que saldrá en la PlayStore sería lo que configures como "Developer name":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio los datos que introduces al registrarte como desarrollador son principalmente para facturación.